# Snakemake Running Remote File Downloads on a Cluster

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, hpc, snakemake

I am trying to download dozens of large files (10-25 GB each) from some public S3 buckets. I am doing this in the context of an HPC cluster that has limited quota for user storage. Typically, I have my Snakemake pipelines under my user directory, but include a symlinked folder (`data`) where large files go.

I tried to run something like the following:

```python
from snakemake.remote.S3 import RemoteProvider as S3RemoteProvider

S3 = S3RemoteProvider()

rule all:
  input: 
    "data/bam/3_month/10X_P4_0.bam", 
    "data/bam/3_month/10X_P4_1.bam", 
    "data/bam/3_month/10X_P4_2.bam"

rule bam_download_s3:
  input:
    bam=lambda wcs: S3.remote("czb-tabula-muris-senis/10x/%s/%s/possorted_genome_bam.bam" % (wcs.age, wcs.sample))
  output:
    "data/bam/{age}/{sample}.bam"
  shell:
    """
    cp {input.bam} {output}
    """
```

although with a scaled-up version where I'm basically downloading everything and am doing this with a `--cluster` and `-j` flags.

I expected this to push out multiple jobs to my cluster and have each download their assigned files. Instead, Snakemake started downloading each file in the local process and into the local folder using the bucket path. I didn't wait for it to exhaust my quota (which it easily would have), but it looked like the cluster jobs would ultimately only copy the local files.

**Is there a way directly in Snakemake to push the downloading to cluster jobs and specify where that downloading is done?**

I can think of some workarounds: E.g., creating a symlinked folder with the bucket name as an alias for Snakemake to dump the temporary files into. Or abandoning Snakemake's RemoteProvider altogether (other than verifying the file exists) and using a separate CLI tool to pull down from S3. However, this all breaks the veneer of transparent usage across remotes that Snakemake seems aimed at providing.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html#amazon-simple-storage-service-s3), "It is important to note that you must have credentials (access_key_id and secret_access_key) which permit read/write access." Do you have your AWS credentials set up? What happens when you run `aws sts get-caller-identity` on the command line?

Comment: @charlesreid1 yeah credentials are fine (Boto3 autoloads them correctly). It downloads, just not in a good place and not in the actual cluster jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test this but maybe it's ok:

```
remote_bam = "czb-tabula-muris-senis/10x/{age}/{sample}/possorted_genome_bam.bam"

rule bam_download_s3:
    input:
        # Some logic to only check the remote file exists and is older than output. 
        # `stay_on_remote= True` may do the trick
        bam=S3.remote(remote_bam, stay_on_remote=True)
    output:
        bam="data/bam/{age}/{sample}.bam"
    params:
        # use this for the wildcard substitution
        bam=remote_bam
    run:
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(output.bam)) # move to dir with lots of space 
        S3.remote(params.bam) # do the actual download
        os.rename(params.bam, output.bam) # move file to final destination
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is helpful (it postpones download), but unfortunately doesn't work. I've updated it to address its minor errors, but generally, running `S3.remote()` doesn't automatically trigger downloading. I've tried making it work by pulling out the remote object (`S3.remote(params.bam).flags['remote_object'].download()`), but that fails too. To me it seems just directly using the `boto3` API would be cleaner than trying to get Snakemake's API to behave how I'd like.